# Is there a way to autogenerate a caption file in html using the Speech Recognition API?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, audio, caption, webvtt

Say I'm creating a youtube-type application, and want to create auto-generated captions. I have the video `.mp4` file, and I want to generate a `.vtt` file for that. Is there anyway to do that with just the `SpeechRecognition` API and `VTTCue`s? Like somehow I get the audio data from the mp4, and run that through the speech recognition api and it generates a transcript?

So far what I've seen is that the SpeechRecognition API can only transcript live microphone output. But is there a way to make it run through audio data?

If this helps, I'm using `react` in my frontend and `node` in my backend.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about accessing the Speech API directly, but with the speech SDK you can send binary audio data directly to the recognizer.

Have a look at

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/get-started-speech-to-text?tabs=windowsinstall&pivots=programming-language-csharp#recognize-from-file

and

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/get-started-speech-to-text?tabs=windowsinstall&pivots=programming-language-csharp#recognize-from-in-memory-stream

All you have to do is to create your audioConfig like

```
var audioConfig = AudioConfig.FromWavFileInput("PathToFile.wav");
```

or

```
var audioConfig = AudioConfig.FromStreamInput(audioInputStream);
```

instead of

```
var audioConfig = AudioConfig.FromDefaultMicrophoneInput();
```

If the problem is with reading an mp4 - nAudio should be able to do that: https://github.com/naudio/NAudio